# Freeing memory allocated via ctypes in Python

Tags: python, c, windows, ctypes, glibc

I have a *ctypes*-based library that wraps a C-library that sometimes allocates memory that needs to be freed. Under Linux this is easy because common *glibc* functionality is been linked into that C library and I can simply call `free()` on it. However, it looks like the same functionality isn't available when I access that third-party-compiled library under Windows.

`ctypes.util.find_msvcrt()` seemed promising, but it returns *None* even though I'm running under Windows. I'm not sure if this means that the source DLL was built with something other than the Microsoft toolchain.

So, I'm left with memory to free and no apparent, simple way to do it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Contact the third party, and tell them to fix their broken API.

Answer (score 5):

When using the MSVCRT you need to ensure that you are using the *same* `free`/ `malloc` pairs from the same CRT (it's possible to have your program running with multiple CRTs). The library you are dealing with seems broken - the library should have a `free` wrapper which invokes the correct version of `free`.

In other words, even if you did manage to find some kind of MSVCRT `free`, there's no guarantee that it's the one you want.

See also http://siomsystems.com/mixing-visual-studio-versions/

Comment: The library can also allow the user to define the allocator that it uses. For example, look at how the [custom memory allocators](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html#customize-memory-allocators) are implemented in CPython. Then via ctypes you can have the library use CPython's [raw memory interface](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html#raw-memory-interface).

Comment: That said, I prefer an API with a two-pass model that returns the allocation size for the user to allocate required memory blocks. If this isn't possible it probably means the library needs to export a `free` function -- e.g. to free a buffer that's specially allocated by some device interface.